# Dealing with data changes in native app

Tags: android, ios, react-native

My background is web development. Last year we started writing a native app with React native and the app is now live and kicking. Everything is working fine, but I'm wondering about the following problem.

With web development - if you have to add a new feature. You just go add it on the server, make modifications to the database, to the client/page and the next time a user visits your website the user can work with your new feature (mostly). But how do you do this on the native side when the user doesn't necessarily always run the latest version of the app?

Following situation.

We have user comments and system generated comments. We didn't account for the fact that we need to translate the system comments in different languages. So lets say that we have this structure for user comment:

```
{
 id: "aqdfkah12"
 author: {name: "xxx"}
 text: 'my comment text"
}
```

and this would be a system comment

```
{
 id: "aqdfkah13"
 author: {name: "system"}
 text: "The task was created."
}
```

In the new version of the app - instead of directly writing the translated string in the database - we are going to save a language constant.

```
{
  id: "aqdfkah13"
  author: {name: "system"}
  text: {languageConstant: 'task_created'}
}
```

This works. In the new version we account for the fact that old comments had a string in the text field and in the new version we have a json. So we are able to show the old comments as they are and have the new system comments translated to the user's locale.
This works with the new version, but the app crashes on previous versions, because the code expected to have a string and now we are trying to directly output a json object and that is not valid.

We cannot possibly predict the database structure of the app for the future. We are always going to change things as the app evolves.

How do you deal with such situations?

Comment: I think solution of this situation is you need to force download updated version of app.

Comment: I suggest make your web API available for v1.0, v2.0 or so on. So `/api/v1.0/` will be always provide string, and `/api/v2.0/` provide new object structure.